# LISP using negative number as exponent

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I've been trying to solve the following Common Lisp question:

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jud0.png)

SO far I have this:

```
(defun activation (type sum) 
  "(type sum)
Returns the activation value of a connectionist unit 
given a sum of products of input activations x 
corresponding connection weights."
  (cond ((equal type 'sigmoid) (- (/ 1 (+ 1 (exp (- 0 sum)))) 0.5))
        ((equal type 'asigmoid) ((/ 1 (+ 1 (exp (- 0 sum))))))
        (t 'unknown-type)))
```

But I keep getting the error "type-error" near the exp function... Can someone help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Your question should stand completely on its own without requiring visitors to click through to anywhere.

Comment: What's the error you get, exactly?

Comment: see also the `case` control structure in Common Lisp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code:

```
((/ 1 (+ 1 (exp (- 0 sum)))))
```

is an invalid expression (it has two parentheses). Change it in

```
(/ 1 (+ 1 (exp (- 0 sum))))
```

In Lisp languages each single parenthesis is a significant syntax token, not as in other languages where `(a + b)` and `((a + b))` denote the same expression.